# How to change GWT Constant locale forcibly and at runtime

Tags: java, spring, gwt, locale, setlocale

I need to change GWT Constant locale to en for some endpoints in Spring application. I can change user locale in the admin panel. And I want to force gwt locale for some constants in some cases no matter what locale settings the user has. My endpoints related to backend. How I can forcibly set en locale?

In my application when I change user locale all constants are changed for all endpoints no matter how I get it - in browser or in postman (without specifying locale parameter in query). I don't know how it works. Class AppContants which inherits com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Constants class doesn't have any methods to set locale.

Answer (score 0):

The locale choices are defined in the module XML. For example, the following module adds multiple locale values:

```
<module>
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N"/>

   <!-- Available Locales -->
   <extend-property name="locale" values="pt"/>
   <extend-property name="locale" values="de"/>
   <extend-property name="locale" values="en"/>

   <!-- Fallback -->
   <set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en"/>
</module>
```

The locale client property can be specified using either a meta tag or as part of the query string in the host page’s URL. If both are specified, the query string takes precedence.

To specify the locale client property using a **meta tag** in the host page, embed a meta tag for gwt:property as follows:

```
<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=en">
```

To specify the locale client property using a **query string**, specify a value for the name locale. For example,

```
https://www.example.org/myapp.html?locale=en
```

To force the locale you want, your app should ignore the user settings in your admin panel and load the locale you want with a query string. Alternatively, if you want the same locale by default for all the users on a page, you can set the meta tag to the locale you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to force to en locale for constants in the backend endpoint. I taught I have to change something when creating Constant bean in java code. I updated the question to clarify

Comment: My answer still applies. Either you enforce the locale with the meta tag, or you load the query string. What exactly is not working?